# data.tables .SD behaves differently in functions that are part of an R package than when they are sourced directly

Tags: r, data.table, r-package

I observed the following weird behaviour of data.tables .SD-notation.
Consider the function

```
min_ex = function(dt,bycols)
{
  dt_sub = dt[, .SD, .SDcols = bycols]
  print(dt_sub)
}
```

This function is supposed to take a data table `dt` and a character vector of column names of `dt`, and just print out these columns.
It works exactly as expected when the function is compiled as part of a script or sourced as a standalone file:

```
library(data.table)

min_ex = function(dt,bycols)
{
  dt_sub = dt[, .SD, .SDcols = bycols]
  print(dt_sub)
}

dt = data.table(x = rep(1,3),y = 1:3)
min_ex(dt,'x')
```

This prints out the x-column in dt.
However, when this function is included in an R package it behaves differently. Specifically, when my work directory is set to the package directory and there is a file in the ./R folder containing this function and I run

```
rm(list = ls())

devtools::load_all()
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(x = rep(1,3),y = 1:3)
min_ex(dt,'x')
```

It prints out "Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)". I put a minimal example package for this on [github](https://github.com/ClaudioHeinrich/data_table_weird_behaviour_demo). This can be installed directly from github and the function then always prints out the Null data table.

I would like to understand why this function behaves differently when it is part of a package and how I can get the function to behave as expected.

What I have tried so far:

- It does not matter whether I use `devtools::load_all` or install the package. The function behaves the same (prints the Null data table). It also behaves the same if you install directly from the github repo link above using `devtools::install_github`.
- I used R 4.2.2 and data.table 1.14.8 and tried this both under Linux and Windows.
- It does not depend on the function arguments being named `dt` and `bycols`. renaming them does not change the behavior.
- It does not depend on whether `data.table` is loaded before or after `devtools::load_all` is run or the example-package is installed. Also including `data.table` as import in the DESCRIPTION file of the example package does not affect behaviour.
- Even weirder: The function above does not return an error when `bycols` is missing, and you just run `min_ex(dt)`. In this case, it behaves as if bycols contains all column names in the data table. I don't understand why this is the case and would expect it to return an error because an argument without default is missing.

Comment: Have you included `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` somewhere in your package (not in a function in the package)? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

Comment: Your package should import data.table if you want to use it inside your package’s functions.

Comment: Your console's current working directory is irrelevant, since you have to either `source` or `library` a function to use it.   Maybe you need to run `find(my_func)` to ensure you are calling the function from the location (.baseEnv, library, etc) that you think you are.

Comment: "Also including data.table as import in the DESCRIPTION file of the example package does not affect behaviour." That is not sufficient. You also need to import it in your NAMESPACE file. You should study *Writing R Extensions*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @r2evans the problem can be solved including `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` in the package code.

It is also sufficient to put data.table as dependency in the DESCRIPTION file using Depends, previously I had only tried Imports.

Comment: It's typically a triple-step required: list in `DESCRIPTION` (in the `Imports:` or `Suggests:`), list in `NAMESPACE` (as a package or the required functions ... typically the former), and include the `.datatable.aware` bit.